# MiniZinc basic problem. n Workers and n Tasks

Tags: artificial-intelligence, variable-assignment, minizinc, declarative

I am learning Minizinc for the first time and am kind of stuck on a very basic problem. It involves n workers and n tasks. I am given a 2D-profit matrix where `profit[w,t]` will give the profit for worker `w` and task `t`. The assignment problem's aim is to maximize the profit.

I have tried the following:

```
include "all_different.mzn";
include "globals.mzn";

int: n = 4;
array [1..n,1..n] of int: profit =
 [| 7,1,3,4 |
    8,2,5,1 |
    4,3,7,2 |
    3,1,6,3 |];

set of int: WORKERS = 1..n;
set of int: TASKS = 1..n;

array[WORKERS] of var TASKS: task;
constraint alldifferent(task);
constraint maximize sum(w in WORKERS) (profit[w,task[w]]);
```

But this does not work, because the maximize function is not set up that way, however I do not know what else to do.
Any tips/solutions?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. The problem is in the last line which should be `solve`, not `constraint`:

```
solve maximize sum(w in WORKERS) (profit[w,task[w]]);
```

The output is:

```
task: [4, 1, 2, 3]
----------
==========
```

Comment: Wauw... Ok. Thanks! That was silly of me.

Comment: @matsfockaert If you think it solves the problem, please accept it as an answer.